# Process does not contain a definition for MainWindowHandle on .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Why doesn't a [`Process` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx) instance contain the [property `MainWindowHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle(v=vs.110).aspx) when using .NET Core framework and what would be the equivalent code for .NET Core?

The following expression works fine when I'm using the classic .NET Framework:

```
Process.GetProcessesByName("processName").FirstOrDefault().MainWindowHandle;
```

When I'm using .NET Core the same expression fails with the following error:

> 'Process' does not contain a definition for 'MainWindowHandle'

- .NET Core version: 1.1
- .NET Framework version: 4.7.2

Comment: .NET Core is meant to be portable. Main windows and their handles are a Windowsism.

Comment: Got it. I should probably rephrase my question: what would be the equivalent code for .NET Core then?

Comment: Depends on why you want to interact with window handles. Imagine this running on Linux, on a console. What's your application expected to do?

Comment: The API is actually available on .net core 2.0 and .net standard 2.0, but will return IntPtr.Zero on non-windows systems.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I'm investigating how to send a window message to a window owned by an other process.

Comment: @MartinUllrich Thanks. I have Core 2.0 installed, I just need to install upgrade Visual Studio to 2017.3 first to be able to use it I guess.

Comment: At present, I'd say there's not much incentive to use .NET Core for something that can only ever run on Windows (and is not ASP.NET Core). The full .NET Framework isn't going away any time soon and there's no risk of missing APIs there.

Comment: @JeroenMostert You're right. I have implemented it with .NET Framework and it's working fine. Thanks for all comments!